# Identifying this ATmega1284P board

Tags: marlin, creality-ender-3, firmware

I recently bought what I am told is an Ender 3 clone. It is a CTC model and has v1-5 written in the bottom corner and comes with a Marlin v1 firmware. But I have no idea what board it is.

When I send command `M115`, I get

```
FIRMWARE_NAME:Marlin V1; Sprinter/grbl mashup for gen6 
FIRMWARE_URL:http://www.mendel-parts.com 
PROTOCOL_VERSION:1.0 
MACHINE_TYPE:CTC 3D 
EXTRUDER_COUNT:1 
UUID:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

Can anybody help me identify this board so I can upgrade the firmware to Marlin 2 in the hopes of getting it to work with Octoprint, and all the safety features that come with the new firmware (such as thermal runaway protection).

[image: Controller board]

Answer (score 1):

This printer controller board looks exactly like an Anet controller board. These also have a v1.5 version:

[image]

Your board misses the "Anet" branding, but includes the 1.5 version designation. Your board is probably customized with a different silkscreen (ink layer that identifies components and other information) on PCBs (printed circuit boars). Rebranding is pretty common in electronics.